# Can't change the size of a UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

I'm trying to add a new window on top of my current one, on an iPad application, but I can't figure out why it always presents itself as fullscreen.
I'm using this code:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];


[window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
ArrowController *controller = [[ArrowController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ArrowController" bundle:nil];   

[window setRootViewController:controller];    
[window setHidden:NO];

[controller release];
```

No matter what size I set on its frame I always get presented with a full screen sized window.
Please advise, thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you can't do with an [NSView][1]?


  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html

Comment: Well I tried to use the presentViewController:animated:completion: but I also could not change the frame. I tried the different options from UIModalPresentationStyle with no avail. Also I have seen others use UIWindows for example with custom alert views.

Answer (score -20, accepted):

iOS apps are only supposed to have one UIWindow object.

you should probably be setting the frame on the UIView of the viewController, and adding it as a subview.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because it is false. iOS apps can have more than one UIWindow and there are many examples of this in  the app store. The official documentation only slightly discourages their use because "usually" you can get what you need via multiple subviews instead.

Answer (score 13):

To change the frame of another UIWindow you add, you have to init your window with the frame you want:

```
self.myNewWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10+20, 300, 440)];
```

Set its property clips to bounds to active:

```
[self.myNewWindow setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

And then after setting your rootViewController to the new window, set its frame too:

```
self.myNewWindow.rootViewController = self.fooViewController;
[self.myNewWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

self.fooViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 440);
```

This is working on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: The key here is to set the ViewController's frame /after/ making the window visible.

Comment: The key should be setting `clipsToBounds = true`.